# Redirect to previous page URL in asp.net core using MVC - c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I searched around and found some are suggesting to use following line. But this gets me current Url and not the previous page url.

```
Request.Headers["Referer"].ToString();
```

I tried to access previous url using below command but getting the error saying *Http request does not contain definition for UrlReferrer*

```
Request.UrlReferrer.ToString();
```

Also tried using *Current* like this

```
HttpContext.Current
```

but still getting the error saying *http request does not contain definition for current*.
Also tried "System.Web.HttpContext.Current" yet receiving error.
What am I missing here?

Comment: Are you using Mvc or Angular?

Comment: using asp.net core MVC

Comment: Can you show us your Route method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should pass your current location when you are navigating to next location, something like `returlurl` in login. There is no any built-in feature for this purpose.

```
<a href="/nexlocation?returnurl=currenturl">my link</a>
```

Comment: I navigating to the 2nd page using click on hyperlink. Can you please tell little bit more on how I could pass location. I am new to asp.net/ programming

Comment: Thank you  @Mehrdad it worked. That was very much helpful. Much appreciate it.